# How to get a string between 2 specific characters in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, char

Having a hard time with Regex.

I have this string:

[image]

I need to replace this whole number "11.000000" with another number.

How do I identify this string by saying:

Give me the string right before "%" until you reach the first blank space (" ")?

Comment: If you're sure that it is always a number, then you can do `\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var myString = "Fixed Breakeven with 11.0000000% Fees";
var number = myString.Split('%').First().Split(' ').Last();
```

Comment: Note that if there is no percent sign this gets the last thing after a space or if there are also no spaces it gets the entire string where as a regular expression would also validate the format of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string pattern = @"^Fixed Breakeven with (\d+(\.\d+)?)% Fees$";
string input = "Fixed Breakeven with 11.0000000% Fees";

var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
string output = string.Empty;

if (match != null)
{
    output = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

[Produces `11.0000000`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5EFixed%20Breakeven%20with%20%28%5Cd%2B%28%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%3F%29%25%20Fees%24&i=Fixed%20Breakeven%20with%2011.0000000%25%20Fees).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also, using regex. This is generic method to fetch decimal from string. It will work for all cases.

```
public static bool ExtractDecimalFromString(string inputString, out Decimal decimalValue)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\D*?((-?(\d+(\.\d+)?))|(-?\.\d+)).*");
        Match match = regex.Match(inputString);
        decimalValue =  match.Success ? Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups[1].Value) : 0;
        return match.Success;
    }
```